# Query limitations due to composite partition keys in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cql

If i have two table structures, one with:
Let this be A,

```
PRIMARY KEY (measureid, statename, reportyear, countyname)
```

and another with, (Let this be B):

```
PRIMARY KEY ((measureid, statename, reportyear), countyname)
```

What are the query limitations of table structure B over A ?
In what queries having composite partition key will pose a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In table A where:

```
PRIMARY KEY (measureid, statename, reportyear, countyname)
```

You can query the table with just `measureid` and it will return rows of `statename`. Specifically:

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ?
```

Alternatively, you can also query with:

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ?
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ? AND reportyear = ?
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ? AND reportyear = ? AND countyname = ?
```

In table B where:

```
PRIMARY KEY ((measureid, statename, reportyear), countyname)
```

You must specify all of `measureid`, `statename`, `reportyear` to query the data. This will return all the rows of *one partition*:

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ? AND reportyear = ?
```

To retrieve *one specific row* of *one partition*:

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ? AND reportyear = ? AND countyname = ?
```

To be clear, you *cannot* query table B with the following:

```
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ?
SELECT FROM ... WHERE measureid = ? AND statename = ?
```

since you must specify the 3 columns of the partition key. I've explained why in this post https://community.datastax.com/questions/7866/. Cheers!